# Get an SVG Map w/ JavaScript to Work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, svg

I have an SVG file, which uses uses JavaScript to add a few styles. This doesn't work in IE8. I don't know if it works in IE9 either, but assume it does. It can be found here:

*removed*

I was told that the project called SVGWeb will allow IE8 to render the SVG and parse the JavaScript to modify the SVG. However, I have downloaded SVGWeb, and the demos don't work in IE8.

I have heard of a few other solutions that allow SVG to work in IE8.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get SVG working in IE8?

Answer (score 1):

Try if the examples here work for you:

http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/15-SVG_in_Internet_Explorer/

Answer (score 0):

After some research, this SVG will not work for IE8.

I guess I need to figure out how to convert this for Flash. SO much for web standards.